# Headless mode buttons are hidden - I think the side drawer is closed?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, chrome, headless

Using webdriver.io and chrome for e2e test. In the browser GUI the test runs fine. But with headless chrome it complains about not finding buttons in the left side  nav bar. I think in headless the width is making it to where the drawer closes and that is why the buttons are not available. But there is no way to know for sure since it is headless.

Anyone know any work around for the issue?

Comment: Try to set the screen width refer to this https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the screen width. Set the screen width by using the function

`browser.setWindowSize(width, height)`

Reference:
[webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize.html](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/setWindowSize.html)

Answer (score 2):

> But there is no way to know for sure since it is headless

[Take screenshots](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/saveScreenshot.html)